# Change gateway on windows 7 from command line

Tags: networking, windows-7

I am trying to find how to change the default gateway on a Windows 7 machine from the DOS prompt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if things have changed with Windows 7 but on XP you could just do something like this.

`route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1`

Comment: You can replace "add" with "change": `route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1`. That is only active until the next DHCP lease renewal or reboot. For a permanent change you need `netsh` with the correct interface name.

Comment: this will NOT *SET* gateway, this will ADD a gateway, therefore if a gateway is already set, windows will  have now two gateways, and produce confusion in a OS that is already screwd up ... GOOD (right now, and ALWAYS, nasty problems in network configuration, for example I set up gw in graphical system, then see it in details, but if I reedit settings, gateway is not set), real answer is the above comment with route change

Answer (score 9):

```
netsh interface ipv4 set route 0.0.0.0/32 "Local Area Connection" 192.168.1.1
```

The name of the network adapter is likely "Local Area Connection".

Comment: When I run this command with "Local Area Connection" used for the name, I get the error: "Element not found". Do I need to use a different name?

Comment: run `netsh interface show interface` to list the available interfaces. you can pick the right one from the list

Comment: the show interface returns the following interface names: Local Area Connection and VirtualBox Host-Only Network. If I try to use Local Area Connection instead of ipv4 I get the following error: "The following command was not found: interface "Local Area Connection" set route 0.0.0.0/32 "Local Area Connection" 192.168.1.1

Comment: you need to use ipv4 too.  See update in my answer.

Comment: +1 netsh is the right way - doing it with a route add will require you to re-add the route each time you reboot the OS.

Comment: This did not work for me on a 2008 R2 server, I also got the "Element not found" error. "route -p change ..." worked like a charm.

Comment: /32 ... REALLY ?!? is ONLY one ip called 0.0.0.0 ?!?

Comment: In windows 10, at least, when I use "set" instead of "add", I get "Element not found" (as the first comment here did).  Changing nothing else except set -> add fixed that error.  It's not clear why to me yet - 'netsh interface ipv4 set route help' says the syntax with 'set' is correct.

Answer (score 7):

The command line given by Cheekaleak does not work for me, this one does:

`netsh int ip set address "Local Area Connection" address=192.168.1.64 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.1.1`

You **have to specify every field** (address, mask and gateway). Otherwise they will be reset.

Answer (score 3):

A persistent way to change the configuration:

```
route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1     
route -p change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: this is much better than netsh, thank you !